# Kotlin nullability check if-else functional approach...How?

Tags: kotlin

For simple check like

```
if (variable != null) {
   doSomething(variable)
}
```

We could change to

```
variable?.let { doSometing(it) }
```

However for a case with else

```
if (variable != null) {
   doSomething(variable)
} else {
   doOtherThing()
}
```

Is there a way of doing so in a single function? Is there something like either?

Comment: FYI what you propose is considered to be a code smell, e.i. it is strongly recommended not to replace `if` with chaining scoping  functions

Comment: Good input @voddan, I'm just thinking if there's way I could get rid of the `!= null` comparison. It makes me feel like one is comparing `if (x != true)` type of feeling.

Comment: I see what you mean. There is no skipping `!= null` in Kotlin , and it is on purpose. Since in Kotlin most types are non-null, the `null` value looses its meaning as universal `false`. I got used to typing it, and it is not so bad. Besides it speeds up reading the code

Comment: BTW, `if (x != true)` is a legitimate code if `x` is `Boolean?`. Go figure ))

Comment: what is the problem with old plain IF THEN ELSE? why so many effort for just a plain and simple stuff like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the elvis-operator `?:` like so:

```
variable?.let { doSomething(it) } ?: doOtherThing()
```

However personally I think that this gets quite unreadable very quickly. There is nothing wrong with an if-expression.

Comment: Ya, agree for simple if-else, it's good. I just don't like to see the `!= null` comparison.

Comment: In addition, you can `variable?.let(::doSomething) ?: doOtherThing()` :D

Comment: What if `doSomething(it)` returns `null`?

Comment: As @voddan stated, this is NOT the same as the original code. `doOtherThing()` will be invoked if `doSomething()` has a nullable return type and returns null.

Comment: Nice catch @voddan!

Comment: I am not really sure if such constructs are more readable than if else. Instead of reading code vertically, we spend the same time reading it horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which might ring well with functional style is the use of when, which is very close to pattern matching:

```
when(variable) {
    null -> doOtherThingSomething()
    else -> doSomething(variable)
}
```

I would argue, however, that you should be careful with abandoning the classic `if` statement, if what you're after is its natural purpose - conditional execution. If you're calculating a value in two different ways and then using it in the same way, this approach makes sense. But if your code paths diverge at this point and don't meet again, then `if` provides a clearer intent.

Comment: I like the if-else style. I just don't like the `!= null` explicit check. `?.let` allow us to get away from using `!= null`, but that only applies to when we handle the positive condition, not both.

Comment: I understand the aversion to explicitly using `null`s - since they are such a plague in Java, but I think it's still worth using when the it's the clearest way to show the intent of the code. And in the case of a piece of procedural code conditioned on the value being null or not, I'd argue that is clearest.

The fact that kotlin doesn't come with an `Optional` type (or equivalent) hints that `null` is a first-class citizen, under its strong null safety mechanism. Don't be afraid to use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can map null-able value if not null by using ternary operator to check not null condition with If...Else Statements.

Here, I had wrote some code snippet to check value null or not ,

> Case 1: value initialized

```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {

   val value:Int ?= 10

   val mapped = value?.let { "Value is == $value" } ?: "Value not initialized..."

   println(mapped)
}
```

You gotta result: Value is == 10

> Case 2: value set remains null

```
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {

   val value:Int ?= null

   val mapped = value?.let { "Value is == $value" } ?: "Value not initialized..."

   println(mapped)
}
```

You gotta result: Value not initialized...